# Does Epson have a road map for its film scanners?

Tags: film-scanner, epson

I have a desire to purchase something like an Epson v850 film scanner.  However given its age I'd like to know if Epson has any published roadmap for future releases of scanners.

Especially as I have seen reports that the v800 was discontinued in 2020, and the v850 was first released around 2014.  The v750 (which the v850 replaced) was released around 2007.  So based on 2007 and 2014, you could guesstimate that a nominal "v950" was due out in 2021.  (However the decline of film in general does work against this).

Note that I am not looking for scanner recommendations, but for reputable information about Epson's potential future product releases.

Comment: My random internet opinion is the most likely roadmap is dropping the line of film scanners. The second most likely is making a more profitable film scanner with fewer features. The market for film scanners is competing with the use of cameras for scanning. Moreover, the scanners that handle large format aren’t designed for planned obsolescence meaning a new model will compete with the old. I’d future proof against a larger pile of negatives needing to be scanned by not waiting. But that’s me.

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens I'm looking for medium format neg scanning.  There are local people who do drum scanning, but their costs are such that I could pay for a V850 in less than a year with just the limited amount of shooting I do

Comment: The v600 will scan 120 rolls and 6x9 medium format sheets.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for speculation regarding potential future products. That is specifically off topic on the SE network, including Photo SE.

Comment: @MichaelC The question is about Epson having a published roadmap.  IMHO that is not speculation.